# Bounded orbits in non-Keplerian central force laws

Tags: classical-mechanics, symmetry, orbital-motion

[Bertrand's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_theorem) famously states that for a central potential $V(r) = r^k$, all bounded orbits are closed if and only if $k = 2$ (harmonic oscillator) or $k = -1$ (Kepler problem). I am curious about what happens in the other cases; we only know that not all bounded orbits are closed. But are generic bounded orbits closed? Are the closed orbits stable? Are the non-closed bounded trajectories 'chaotic' or are they close to periodic?